# How to have model method run automatically if field is greater than 12

Tags: python, django, django-models

If my model field hours is more than 12.0 I want end_time to be set automatically without the user having to save or even be in the app. Is there a way to do this in a model method without the user having to save the time entry?

Models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    TUID = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    seconds_paused = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    pause_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    pause_time_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    def _str_(self):
        return self.TUID

    def timeStop(self):
        if self.hours >= 12:
           self.end_time = timezone.now()
        return self.end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, but I will assume that what you mean is that when the object is saved, you want to automatically set the `end_time` if it is not already set.  One option is to do this in a [`pre_save` hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), but I prefer to overwrite the [`save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save).  Something like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.hours >= 12) and not self.end_time:
           self.end_time = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```